# Installed mysql 8 on Mac then mysql 5.7 now now they wont work

Tags: mysql-5.7, mac-os-x, mysql-8.0

I have a brand new Macbook pro with Mojave. I installed mysql 8 using the dmg file but realized that Sequel Pro is not playing nice with it and after researching I decided to install mysql 5.7. This time I installed brew and did it. Sequel pro keeps shutting down and my previous database is showing up even though I thought I removed it. Before I reset the mac and start over, is there a way I can completely remove mysql ( all versions ) from the computer and reinstall using brew just the 5.7 version?

If this is the wrong place to ask kindly let me know where I should ask and I will.

Comment: What Sequel Pro version? What is 'not playing nicely' exactly? Could it be just Sequel pro caching the previous database names?

Answer (score 0):

If you originally installed mysql from mysql.com, then the installer adds a "mysql" section in your system preferences which has an "uninstall" button there.